# Custom integratedTerminal Icon Color and Name for every debug option

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have VS Code workspace with two projects, back-end and front-end. Inside each project I have different launch options:
Launch Django application
Compound: Launch Celery Worker, Launch Celery Beat
Launch Node React

I want to achieve result that can be found on screenshot here: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PihR1.jpg)

Basically I want to launch VS Code integratedTerminal with selected profile\settings for my every debugging configurations, so I can easily differentiate them.